Traefik sometimes redirecting to the wrong service
I have a very strange problem with my traefik configuration.
I got 1 front end web application in React, and 1 back end API in C#.
Here's a part of my docker-compose file :
backend:
    container_name: euroguessr-backend
    image: euroguessr-backend
    environment:
      - ConnectionStrings__DatabaseConnection=Server=db;Port=$POSTGRES_PORT;Database=$POSTGRES_DB;Username=$POSTGRES_USER;Password=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;
    depends_on:
      - db
      - traefik
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=(Host(`$DOMAIN_NAME`) && PathPrefix(`/api`))"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.services.backend.loadbalancer.server.port=$BACKEND_PORT"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.tls.certresolver=euroguessr"

frontend:
    container_name: euroguessr-frontend
    image: euroguessr-frontend
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`$DOMAIN_NAME`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=$FRONTEND_PORT"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.tls.certresolver=euroguessr"
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - traefik

As you can see, every request starting with "/api" should be redirected by traefik to my C# API.
Strangely, when I try to access to the endpoint "https://dev.euroguessr.com/api/song/search?page=1&rowsNumber=25", I am sometimes redirected to my frontend application.
Do you know if I made a mistake in my configuration, or is it just a temporary Traefik bug when I start the traefik container ?
